# How to draw a dotted line in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I want to draw a dotted grid on a TPaintbox canvas in a Firemonkey project, the outcome should be exactly like this:

[image]

To start with I thought I would draw the vertical dotted lines and then the horizontal dotted lines, so with that in mind I attempted to draw a single line first in attempt to get the appearance just right, this is what I tried:

```
Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Black;
Canvas.Stroke.Dash := TStrokeDash.Dot;
Canvas.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
Canvas.Stroke.Thickness := 1;
Canvas.DrawLine(PointF(0, 0), PointF(0, 150), 1);
```

The result is not what I had hoped, in fact the `TLine` shape can do a dotted line how I want it to:

[image]

But I need to do this drawing myself on the canvas and not use additional controls. For the record `TLine` simply needs the Stroke.Dash property changing to Dot.

So, using the canvas in a Firemonkey project how may I draw a dotted line the same as `TLine` does so that I can draw a grid like the first sample image?

Comment: Just a note I am adding here, setting the thickness to 2 shows as a dotted line but not small/fine enough.

Comment: Additional note, didn't realise you can use float values like 0.5 for thickness but still cannot get the drawn line looking right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without going into the 'why it works' you can achieve 1 pixel dotted line (like in `TLine`) by adding (or subtracting) half the line width to the coordinates. I got the idea when tracing through what `TLine` does; during rendering it uses

```
InflateRect(Result, -(FStroke.Thickness / 2), -(FStroke.Thickness / 2));
```

Applying the 0.5 modification to the line coordinates, gives the same result.

```
procedure TForm24.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas);
var
  a: integer;
begin
  Canvas.BeginScene;
  try
    Canvas.Stroke.Dash := TStrokeDash.Dot;

    for a := 0 to 10 do
      Canvas.DrawLine(PointF(a * 20 + 0.5, 0.5), PointF(a * 20 + 0.5, 200.5), 1);

    for a := 0 to 10 do
      Canvas.DrawLine(PointF(0.5, a * 20 + 0.5), PointF(200.5, a * 20 + 0.5), 1);

    Canvas.DrawLine(PointF(0.5, 0.5), PointF(200.5, 200.5), 1);
    Canvas.DrawEllipse(RectF(5.0, 5.0, 195.5, 195.5), 1);
  finally
    Canvas.EndScene;
  end;
end;
```

produces this result:

[image]
[image]

Magnifier view is 500%

**Edit 2018.02.23**:

An alternative way, worth to test, is to change **the forms** `Quality` property to `HighPerformance`

Comment: Fantastic! Admittedly I don't use Firemonkey until now really but I can see some of the magic in your answer :)

Comment: And good spot looking into TLine, I also tried looking through the source but things are not always clear to me.